# Can you please add more "Why" into the Help centre?

Tags: discussion

When you're flying and you get the air craft training demonstration, they tell you `Help yourself with the air mask before others`. It annoys me that they don't say why `because you can succum to hypoxia within 15 seconds after rapid decompression`. The why makes it memorable and would likely increase the amount of people following the advice in practice.

This fledgling group is a bit like the aircraft training video for me at the moment. There might be good reasons for the rules, but the reasons a buried in this meta forum.

Could you please consider the following

1) Start with a more precise opening statement

> Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about
>   professionally managed networks in a business environment.

On its own some of the rules that follow don't make total sense. Perhaps this could be expanded.

> Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about
>   professionally managed networks in a business environment. It was
>   started because such questions would get lost in Super User, Server
>   Fault, and others.

2) Link each rule directly to the Meta topic.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this question before. We used to have more reasoning, but the users complained that it was too wordy and turned people off so that they didn't read it. Personally, I don't think they read it anyway, and I'm not too worried about the length, but you may want to bump this again to see if more discussion will follow.